# One Sample, one sided Hypothesis test with T-stat

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, econometrics

I am new in R and for my class, I am trying to write the codes for one sample, a one-sided t-test for the alternative hypothesis B<0. As you probably can understand, weight is the independent variable I want to test. I wrote:

t.test(Data$weight, alternative = "less", mu = 0, paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE)

For some mistake I did, I am receiving a p value=1 where it is certainly should be 0.1.

I know I can find the p-value from the two-sided test but I want to be able to do it this way. Would you please point out my mistake or suggest a fix, a better option?

Comment: You will need to provide some information on your data in order to receive a meaningful answer.  What is the mean and standard deviation of "Data$weight"

Comment: I did not think it was necessary because I thought the codes were wrong for sure since I know the results. But here they are. The variable name is different but context is same.                                                                                
mean(lstat)
[1] 11.544
> sd(lstat)
[1] 6.655732
>

Comment: Felix, if your test is B<0 yet the mean of your data is greater than zero, than I would expect a p value of 1.  You may want to rerun the test with “greater” as the alternative.

Comment: How is there a relation between the mean of the true coefficient and the mean of the data of the independent variable? Independent variable can as well be something negatively affecting the dependent variable with a negative beta?

Comment: Ah, so I am using definitely the wrong code function. Function coeftest tests the significance of the independent variable from its coefficient as it should be but I guess it is only two-sided. Thank you, Dave. At least I know where it is wrong.

Comment: The t test as you have written is testing if the mean of data$weight is less than zero, from the previous comment you responded that the mean was 11.5.  The the test is unlikely true, thus a high p value.  I don’t think the t test is the correct test based on the last comments

Comment: Yes, the test I am using is wrong certainly. Correct one must be a hypothesis test based on coefficients.